# Mongodb upsert document or $addToSet

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, upsert

So I am trying to figure out the best way to do this. I have a dump of documents that I put into a collection. That includes a ID and a timestamp that is a array. Basically what I would like to accomplish is if there is collision on the ID I want to push the new timestamp to the array else I want to upsert the entire document. I don't know if it changes anything but I am using pymongo.

Answer (score 0):

The [`$addToSet` operator](http://%20https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) can be used together with upsert if you want to keep unique timestamps as well. Otherwise, [`$push` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#up._S_push) will serve to add each timestamp to the end of the array when there is a collision on the `ID` field.

A sample query to achieve this is as follow:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
from time import time

client = MongoClient()
db = client.experiments

id_ = ObjectId('5b6d2a8ed35b7caf9fde936f')
ts = time() + 300

db.sample.update_one(
    {'ID': id_}, # filter
    {'$addToSet': {'timestamp': ts}}, # update
    upsert=True
)
```

More information on [`pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one`](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.update_one) is documented.